# Implementar Teclado Numérico

Tags: android

Estou mexendo em um aplicação que é necessária que insira números para fazer os cálculos necessários, porém eu gostaria de que quando o usuário selecionasse o Text Field em ver de aparecer o teclado alfabético, aparecesse o teclado numérico. Como se faz para implementar essa função?

Answer (score 4):

É só você configurar o tipo de input de sua EditText no arquivo XML.

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"/>
```

Ou se preferir, pode fazer isto pelo próprio Java:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Links que podem lhe ser úteis:

- [Input Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)
- [Input Method Type](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Comment: Perfeito. Deu certo aqui, implementei via XML mesmo para não dar confusão pra mim depois. Valeu.

Comment: De nada, @King. Se desejar, marque como resolvido. Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

É bem fácil, só precisa configurar o tipo de input de sua EditText no arquivo XML.

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"/>
```

Ou em java:

```
edittext1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Caso você seja um usuário do aplicativo [Sketchware](http://sketchware.io)
[image: sk]